# getting values of options from select in clojure

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I want to know how I can write this javascript function to get values from select options in Clojure function .

```
<select id="namelist">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

I want to write the below javascript function for same in clojurescript

```
var e = document.getElementById("namelist");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Anyone please tell me what will be its corresponding code in clojurescript

Comment: I have tried this 

     (defn get-value-by-id [id]
       (->> id (.getElementById js/document ) .-value))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transscript would be:

```
(let [e (js/document.getElementById "namelist")]
  (.-text (aget (.-options e) (.-selectedIndex e))))
```